# Symfony3 FOSElasticaBundle doc example not working

Tags: php, symfony, foselasticabundle

I am trying to set up FOSElasticaBundle. 
Composer json entry:

```
"friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle": "^3.2"
```

I was following official [docs](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/blob/3.2.x/Resources/doc/setup.md) tutorial, 
but this line doesn't work:

```
$finder = $this->container->get('fos_elastica.finder.app.user');
```

error i get:

> You have requested a non-existent service "fos_elastica.index.app.user".

**Do you have any idea why ?**

 
Things i checked:

- AppKernel.php contains *'new FOS\ElasticaBundle\FOSElasticaBundle(),'*
- Profiler under 'Configuration' tab does not show 'FOSElastica' as enabled :(

*config.yml:*

```
fos_elastica:
    clients:
        default: { host: localhost, port: 9200 }
    indexes:
        app:
            types:
                user:
                    mappings:
                        email: ~
                    persistence:
                        # the driver can be orm, mongodb, phpcr or propel
                        # listener and finder are not supported by
                        # propel and should be removed
                        driver: orm
                        model: AppBundle\Entity\User
                        provider: ~
                        listener: ~
                        finder: ~
```

Thanks in advance for any insights, guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out bundle didn't install properly.

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
```

in composer.json on fresh installation worked